# Google Apps Script: terminate/stop/cancel execution programaticaly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to stop/cancel the execution from the script side (Google Sheets)?
Maybe there is some class to use or is it only possible to set a return on a function I want to stop/cancel?

My scenario: Opens a sidebar with "Start" and "Stop" buttons. On start, starts the script. On "stop", I want to stop that specific execution/script.
This is what the onClick function looks like:

```
  function runDomains() {
    const input = {
      col : 1,
      row: 1,
      toogleCheck: document.querySelector('#flexSwitchCheckChecked').classList[1]
    }
    console.log(input);
    runButton.innerText = 'Working...';
    runButton.disabled = true;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(done).startScript(input)
 }
```

I found this [forum record](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153206695/exit-apps-script-if-condition-is-met?hl=en), but they just mention "return" option on function.

Comment: Return would work but it would depend specifically on the context of your code. I think if you could provide more information of what you are doing with your code we may be able to find how you would need to use a return within it..

Answer (score -1):

Sure, but doing it programmatically would require you to define conditions which would logically trigger the script to end, and you would need to design a way to evaluate these conditions when necessary.  This is a very common task.  Put some more thought into what you're trying to accomplish and you should develop the logical conditions intuitively.

Comment: this might be better shared as a comment rather than an "Answer", or provide a code snip that demonstrates what you mean.

Comment: Commenting to OP was likely my first inclination, but the site says I need at least 49 more reputation.  But that's a moot point because I agree with you that my answer lacks useful details, and in retrospect I shouldn't have chimed in at all.